# GCP Instance group with less than requested instances for a long time

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a GKE cluster with a single node pool, and the associated instance group has been with less than the required number of instances for more than 12h, recently it changed to 0 instances.

I see this warning on each of the members:

```
Instance 'gke-development-default-pool-85b569a4-6j60' creation failed: The zone 'projects/myproject/zones/europe-west6-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.
```

Any ideas about what might be going on are very welcome, with 0 instances all the service of the cluster are down. Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message means that there is not enough capacity in europe-west6-a to provision the instances from your node pool. Region capacity is being monitored actively but in rare cases it can run out, however such events don't last for very long. Try creating your node pool again every 4-7 hours, see if more resources become available.

Assuming you have a zonal cluster, I can suggest trying to deploy the node pool in a different zone, and if you're tying to deploy a regional cluster, you might want consider using a different region altogether.

You can also check out [this article from Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/#locations) on where each region is located so you can choose which one fits your needs better.